# Escaping to return `TEXT[]` type with a `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` and `VALUES` statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, execute, return-query

I'm trying to return `TEXT[]` type from `my_func()` with a [RETURN QUERY EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) and [VALUES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html) statement.

But calling `my_func()` which has `"` in `''` got the error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF TEXT[] AS $$
BEGIN               -- ↓              ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓           ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓  ↓
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'VALUES (ARRAY["a","b"]), (ARRAY["c","d"])';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
ERROR:  column "a" does not exist
LINE 1: VALUES (ARRAY["a","b"]), (ARRAY["c","d"])
                      ^
QUERY:  VALUES (ARRAY["a","b"]), (ARRAY["c","d"])
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

And, calling `my_func()` which has `'` in `""` got the error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF TEXT[] AS $$
BEGIN               -- ↓              ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓           ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓  ↓
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE "VALUES (ARRAY['a','b']), (ARRAY['c','d'])";
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
ERROR:  column "VALUES (ARRAY['a','b']), (ARRAY['c','d'])" does not exist
LINE 1: "VALUES (ARRAY['a','b']), (ARRAY['c','d'])"
        ^
QUERY:  "VALUES (ARRAY['a','b']), (ARRAY['c','d'])"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Actually, I could return `TEXT[]` type from `my_func()` with a `RETURN QUERY` and `VALUES` statement without error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF TEXT[] AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES (ARRAY['a','b']), (ARRAY['c','d']);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
 my_func
---------
 {a,b}
 {c,d}
(2 rows)
```

So, how can I return `TEXT[]` type from `my_func()` with a `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` and `VALUES` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Escaping `'` in `''` with these ways below, you can return `TEXT[]` type from `my_func()` with a [RETURN QUERY EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) and [VALUES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF TEXT[] AS $$
BEGIN                              -- ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓            ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'VALUES (ARRAY[''a'',''b'']), (ARRAY[''c'',''d''])';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF TEXT[] AS $$
BEGIN               -- ↓               ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓            ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE E'VALUES (ARRAY[\'a\',\'b\']), (ARRAY[\'c\',\'d\'])';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 2 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
 my_func
---------
 {a,b}
 {c,d}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: A simple example like this doesn't need plpgsql, you could write this function in sql as well. It depends of the rest of your needs if that works well in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use [named/tagged dollar `$x$` quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) outside, and regular single-quotes inside: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gihDgZ0K)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF TEXT[] AS $f$
BEGIN               -- ↓                ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE $q$VALUES (ARRAY['a','b']), 
                                 (ARRAY['c','d'])
                       $q$;
END;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM my_func();
```

| my_func |
| --- |
| {a,b} |
| {c,d} |